# simple xpath to find specific information

Tags: xml, xpath

I've been given the task to find all the movies containing the role-name "skywalker".

```
     </Subsidiary>

     <Subsidiary id="Lucasfilms">

    <Movie>
    <Name lang="en">Star Wars: The Force Awakens</Name>
    <Year>2015</Year>
    <ScreenTime unit="minutes">135</ScreenTime>
    <Cast>
      <Role name="Han Solo" actor="HarrisonFord" />
      <Role name="Rey" actor="DaisyRidley" />
      <Role name="Kylo Ren" actor="AdamDriver" />
      <Role name="Finn" actor="JohnBoyega" />
      <Role name="Luke Skywalker" actor="MarkHamill" />
      <Role name="Supreme Leader Snoke" actor="AndySerkis" />
      <Role name="C-3PO" actor="AnthonyDaniels" />
      <Role name="Poe Dameron" actor="OscarIsaac" />
      <Role name="General Hux" actor="DomhnallGleeson" />
     </Cast>
      </Movie>

 i've tried //Disney/Subsidiaries/Subsidiary/Movie/Cast [contains(./Role, 
 'Skywalker')] this does not work
```

I want it to return me the names of the movie that has the name skywalker in it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use

```
/Subsidiary/Movie[Cast/Role[contains(@name,'Skywalker')]]/Name
```

to return the `Name` element of the `Movie` element.

Comment: this return the name of the person, i want it to return the movie's name. 
//Disney/Subsidiaries/Subsidiary/Movie[Cast/Role[contains(@name,'Skywalker')]]/Movie, something like this, only that i get error witht his one